# TypeScript Cloud Functions import module from parent or sibling directory

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions

I want to be able to separate the `functions` dir from my `domain` dir. As of now, I can't deploy to Cloud Functions in those circumstances.

```
project
 |- functions
 |   |- src 
 |      |- index.ts
 |- domain
     |- index.ts
```

I looked into the provided log, but couldn't understand the problem, or how to fix it.

```
i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint <PROJECT_DIR>/functions
> tslint --project tsconfig.json


ERROR: <PROJECT_DIR>domain/file.ts:1:84 - expected nospace before colon in call-signature
ERROR: <PROJECT_DIR>domain/file.ts:26:7 - Missing semicolon
ERROR: <PROJECT_DIR>domain/file.ts:35:2 - file should end with a newline
ERROR: <PROJECT_DIR>domain/file.ts:35:2 - Missing semicolon

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `tslint --project tsconfig.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     ~/.npm/_logs/2019-11-14T16_50_55_316Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ deploy: `firebase deploy --only functions`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     ~/.npm/_logs/2019-11-14T16_50_55_801Z-debug.log
```

Log1:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.14.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   '--prefix',
1 verbose cli   '<PROJECT_DIR>/functions',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'lint' ]
2 info using npm@6.13.0
3 info using node@v11.14.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prelint', 'lint', 'postlint' ]
5 info lifecycle functions@~prelint: functions@
6 info lifecycle functions@~lint: functions@
7 verbose lifecycle functions@~lint: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle functions@~lint: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:<PROJECT_DIR>/functions/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:<PROJECT_DIR>/functions/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
9 verbose lifecycle functions@~lint: CWD: <PROJECT_DIR>/functions
10 silly lifecycle functions@~lint: Args: [ '-c', 'tslint --project tsconfig.json' ]
11 silly lifecycle functions@~lint: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
12 info lifecycle functions@~lint: Failed to exec lint script
13 verbose stack Error: functions@ lint: `tslint --project tsconfig.json`
13 verbose stack Exit status 2
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:193:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:193:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:999:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:266:5)
14 verbose pkgid functions@
15 verbose cwd <PROJECT_DIR>
16 verbose Darwin 19.0.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.14.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "--prefix" "<PROJECT_DIR>/functions" "run" "lint"
18 verbose node v11.14.0
19 verbose npm  v6.13.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2
22 error functions@ lint: `tslint --project tsconfig.json`
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the functions@ lint script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 2, true ]
```

Log2:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.14.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'deploy' ]
2 info using npm@6.13.0
3 info using node@v11.14.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predeploy', 'deploy', 'postdeploy' ]
5 info lifecycle functions@~predeploy: functions@
6 info lifecycle functions@~deploy: functions@
7 verbose lifecycle functions@~deploy: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle functions@~deploy: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:<PROJECT_DIR>/functions/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
9 verbose lifecycle functions@~deploy: CWD: <PROJECT_DIR>/functions
10 silly lifecycle functions@~deploy: Args: [ '-c', 'firebase deploy --only functions' ]
11 silly lifecycle functions@~deploy: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle functions@~deploy: Failed to exec deploy script
13 verbose stack Error: functions@ deploy: `firebase deploy --only functions`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:193:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:193:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:999:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:266:5)
14 verbose pkgid functions@
15 verbose cwd <PROJECT_DIR>/functions
16 verbose Darwin 19.0.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.14.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "deploy"
18 verbose node v11.14.0
19 verbose npm  v6.13.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error functions@ deploy: `firebase deploy --only functions`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the functions@ deploy script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I'm only now starting with TypeScript and Cloud Functions, so probably I'm doing a rookie mistake (for which I already apologize). Could anyone give me a help on this?

Comment: I'm not clear at all about the problem you're running in to.  Please edit the question to explain you mean "separate the functions from my domain dir"?  Are there any error messages?  If so, include them.  Your question should contain enough information that anyone can reproduce the issue exactly as you see it.

Comment: @DougStevenson sorry. I edited the question, thank you.

Comment: The error is showing tslint errors.  Were you expecting something different?  If so, what?  What's your code?

Comment: Simply moved the function from the `functions/index.ts` to the `domain/index.ts`, and suddenly it started showing those errors when deploying to Cloud Functions. I assume that's something to do with the fact that the file is not in the `functions/index.ts`. As so, how could I import something in `functions/index.ts` that is in a parent or sibling dir?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create a file structure like the one you described. 
Here are the key points that made it work:

Make sure that you set the "main" property in the package.json. This indicates the file where the function(s) are:

```
"main": "./functions/src/index.ts"
```

Make sure you export the functions in the domain/index.ts file, so they are available from the outside:

```
exports.helloWorld = () => {
  return "Hello World"
};
```

Make sure that you reference the domain/index.ts file from functions/src/index.ts like this:

```
const domain = require('../../domain/index.ts');
```

References:

- [Structuring the Code docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/#structuring_source_code)
- [Specifying dependencies docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs)